# prevent user picking a future time in blackberry + java

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Can you please tell me how to set a date field to not allow future times to be chosen in blackberry + java?

The user is able to set future times, but I need the user to only be able to set **past** or **current** times - not future.  Is it possible in blackberry + java?

```
if (field.equals(datePickerBtn)) {

    final DateTimePicker dateTimePicker = DateTimePicker
            .createInstance(Calendar.getInstance(), /*"dd:MM:yyyy"*/null, "HH:mm");

    Calendar maxCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    maxCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);           
    dateTimePicker.setMaximumDate(maxCalendar);
    Calendar minCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    minCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1900);
    dateTimePicker.setMinimumDate(minCalendar);
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (dateTimePicker.doModal()) {
                calendar = dateTimePicker.getDateTime();

                Date date = calendar.getTime(); 
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yyyy HH:mm");
                selectedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
                dateEditTxt.setText(selectedDate);                                  
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Calendar.getInstance()`, the returned `Calendar` will be set to the current time and date. This, in your case, could be made your maximum with:

```
dateTimePicker.setMaximumDate(Calendar.getInstance());
```

This should set your `DateTimePicker` maximum to the current time.

If you want to exert more control over the maximum date value, you can use `Calendar#set(int, int)` to fine tune the `Calendar` object, just as you've done above.

For example, to create two `Calendar` objects, `maximum` for the current time and `minimum` for the actual minimum time that `Calendar` is capable of representing, and display their values:

```
Calendar minimum = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar maximum = Calendar.getInstance();

minimum.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
minimum.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
minimum.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
minimum.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
// For Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1 is the actual minimum.
// 0 will underflow to the last day of the previous month.
minimum.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
// For Calendar.MONTH, months are numbered 0 (Jan) through to 11 (Dec).
minimum.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
// For Calendar.YEAR, both 0 and 1 represent year 1CE.
minimum.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
```

See also: [Java ME Oracle documentation for Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/cldc1.1/jsr139/java/util/Calendar.html).

Comment: @Nate Was not aware that BlackBerry was based on Java ME, approached question as pure Java question. If it is incorrect, I will delete the answer. I wonder if the above code worked for OP as it was accepted as correct.

Comment: Modified. After reading the J2ME docs, this should compile. Please advise if further modification is required.

Comment: I had to fix the Oracle link ... 404 for me.  But, still, +1 worthy now :)

Answer (score 4):

<strike>[The accepted answer given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279706/119114) is not correct</strike> (answer fixed). <strike>BlackBerry Java does not support the full set of standard Java APIs, including `Calendar#clear()`.  So, that code won't even *compile*.</strike>

[Here is the relevant API documentation you need to use](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/java/util/Calendar.html), which you may need to adjust if you're supporting a lower version of BBOS than 7.0.

Your original code is nearly correct already.  Just remove a couple of lines to give:

```
  final DateTimePicker dateTimePicker = 
      DateTimePicker.createInstance(Calendar.getInstance(), 
                                    /*"dd:MM:yyyy"*/null, 
                                    "HH:mm");

  Calendar maxCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  dateTimePicker.setMaximumDate(maxCalendar);
  Calendar minCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  minCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1900);
  dateTimePicker.setMinimumDate(minCalendar);
```

In your original code, you were hardcoding the maximum year value to 2013, which is not going to work correctly after one more month.

You didn't specify exactly how you wanted to determine the **minimum** date, so I can't comment on whether or not you need to set additional fields (besides year = 1900) in your minimum date.